# Get list of all JIRA project milestones

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to get a list of all project milestones in JIRA using the Python API. Example `JQL` is `project =A100S AND labels = Milestone`. This is what I tried:

```
from jira import JIRA   
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'password'), options={'server':'https://MY_JIRA.atlassian.net'})
jql = "project =A100S AND labels = Milestone"
jira_search = jira.search_issues(jql)
```

This does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

JQL used to get issues. You can look for example of getting milestones with JIRA in heading "Milestones" in https://docs.easyagile.com/easy-agile-programs/advanced-programs-usage/easy-agile-programs-api/